# How to use now() with Eloquent?

Tags: php, date, eloquent, slim-3

What the best way to use now() with Eloquent? I mean, is there a native Eloquent function to return today's date? I'm using Slim framework and for this query, the only solution that I found is:

```
$now = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', time());

$articles = Article::where('created_at', '<', $now)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

It's a bit messy, isn't it?
I could use Carbon but it would make an extra dependency...

Thanks

Comment: Time is implied `date('Y/m/d H:i:s', time());` can be `date('Y/m/d H:i:s');`  Have you tried `DB::raw('now()')`  I should note that MySQL, and PHP use separate Time settings, so if you have different timezone set in one and not the other, ... yea that can be fun.  I only use PHP time, now because of that .. lol

Comment: Oh, I was sure I tried this solution ... Bad writing, no doubt. Thanks it works

Comment: Haha, and I don't use Larval or Eloquent, I actually detest query builders and ORMs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options here: either use `DB::raw` method to make `where` method process the given expression as is:

```
$articles = Article::where(DB::raw('created_at < NOW()'))
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->limit(10)
                    ->get();
```

... or use `whereRaw` method:

```
$articles = Article::whereRaw('created_at < NOW()')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->limit(10)
                    ->get();
```

As a sidenote, Eloquent has several helper methods for datetime-related processing - `whereDate`, `whereMonth`, `whereDay`, `whereYear` and `whereTime`. I'm really not sure those can be used in this specific case, but they might turn helpful elsewhere.

Comment: whereRaw works perfectly. Many thanks for your answer.